# complicated sql command

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a sql table with the following records:

```
+------+----------+
| user |   dob    |  
+------+----------+
| john | 1/10/96  | 
| jane | 3/4/97   | 
| jill | 1/8/96   | 
| jack | 2/9/00   |
| jane | 12/14/07 | 
| john | 1/11/98  | 
+------+----------+
```

Here's the command I want to execute: delete all users with dob < 1/1/00 but keep a user if there exists another user with the same name whose dob >= 1/1/00.

In this example, the johns and jill would be deleted and the janes and jack would stay.

How do I translate the above command into sql?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, what you are saying is valid but that's doesn't mean you will go on downvoting the correct answer ... right?

Comment: Why would jack be deleted?

Comment: I'm satisfied that the accepted answer at the link provided is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE EXISTS` like

```
delete from `user` u
where dob < '1/1/00'
and exists (select 1 from `user`
                where name = u.name and dob >= '1/1/00');
```

Comment: `SELECT '1/11/00' < '1/2/00'` -> true

Comment: I tried the above answer and MySQL is telling me my syntax is wrong. @Rahul can you please explain what each line in this command is doing so I can debug?